# ¿Son "hasta cuando" y "hasta donde" conjunciones temporales?

Tags: conjunciones

> Poco a poco había ido cayendo en la rutina de visitar a las ya
>   establecidas, acostándose con ellas **hasta donde** le sirvieran,
>   **hasta donde** le fuera posible, **hasta cuando** tuvieran vida.

¿Se pueden considerar *hasta cuando* y *hasta donde* como conjunciones temporales?

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Yo no diría que son conjunciones temporales. Una *conjunción* es una palabra, nunca un conjunto de palabras. En todo caso, podría discutirse si es una *locución conjuntiva*, pero yo tampoco diría que es una locución.

Si te fijas, se trata de una proposición subordinada adverbial propia temporal. Si dices que *hasta cuando* es la conjunción/locución conjuntiva, también tendría que ser el nexo que una la subordinada a la principal, y dado que es propia, se tendría que poder sustituir por el adverbio *entonces*, con lo cual te quedaría algo como:

*"Poco a poco había ido cayendo en la rutina de visitar a las ya establecidas, acostándose con ellas **entonces**, **entonces**, **entonces**."*

En su lugar, en mi opinión la sustitución correcta tendría que ser algo como:

*"Poco a poco había ido cayendo en la rutina de visitar a las ya establecidas, acostándose con ellas **hasta entonces**, **hasta entonces**, **hasta entonces**."*

De todo ello, sólo se puede concluir que el *hasta* no debe permanecer a la subordinada, y por lo tanto no puede formar una locución con *donde* y *cuando* (ello las haría inseparables). Lo que tienes es tres complementos circunstanciales de tiempo (iniciados por *hasta*), que son también sintagmas preposicionales, cuya preposición es *hasta*, y su término (todo lo demás), la subordinada propiamente dicha. Entonces, *donde*, *cuando* y *cuando* serían los nexos de la subordinada, y no *hasta donde*, *hasta cuando* y *hasta cuando*.